# I didn't see any data on data grid view. Localdb didn't send any data (northwind)

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, entity-framework, windows-forms-designer

I'm making a windows form app. I'm using Northwind database but localdb didn't send any data. I just see category names on grid view...[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQsVh.png)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (Northwindcontext context=new Northwindcontext())
        {
            dgwProduct.DataSource = context.Products.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does context have any data?  It looks like you are creating a new instance of the context and need to query the database to get the data.

Comment: Yes, Context have data

Comment: @Utku karagül, do you mean the Northwind database comes from [Get the Northwind sample database for Microsoft Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/downloading-sample-databases#northwind_access)?  If so, can you tell me how do you add ADO.NET Entity Data Model from your app? As usual, your code should work.

Comment: I don't understand clearly. Can u explain more?

Comment: @Utku karagül, is your database a access database or a sql server database? Based on my test, if your database has the data and your database is sql server, the datagirdview will show the data.

Comment: I fixed the error, thanks!

Comment: @Utku karagül, I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved and if you don't mind, you can make an answer click '✔' to mark your reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (Northwindcontext context=new Northwindcontext())
            {
      context.Products.Load();
    
                dgwProduct.DataSource =  context.Products.Local.ToBindingList();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you put break point in the on load method?  The Load event may not be registered.